# Loop through HTML table and update values with AJAX GET

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have built a small application in ASP.NET Core MVC where you select a shipment and it will loop through all the images in blob storage and display them in the web page. The web page needs to load, and then the images after as It can be a heavy call.

Below is the HTML I have -

```
<table id="ImageTable">
        <tr>
        <th>
            Img
        </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var shipment in Model.shipmentImages)
            {
                <td class="ImageCell">@shipment.RowKey</td>
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and below is the AJAX, which does seem to be working when debugging, just the webpage doesn't get updated.

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ImageTable td.ImageCell').each(function () {
        var cellItem = $(this);
        console.log(cellItem.html);
        console.log(cellItem);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://localhost:5001/Shipment/GetImage?' + $(this).html(),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log($(this.html));
                console.log(data);
                cellItem.append(data.html);
            }
    });
});
    </script>
}
```

I can see in the console that the HTML data that I'm looking for gets returned however the cells in the table don't update with the new HTML.

Thanks

Comment: And what `console.log(data.html)` return

Comment: And `console.log($(this.html));` will likely not show anything useful

Comment: Since this is not a server issue, perhaps post only rendered HTML?

Comment: The question description, the method name `GetImage` and terms like "*the HTML data*" imply you are returning the binary image from your MVC action, not HTML (text).  Is that the case?

Comment: Thanks guys. Turns out it works without using .html! Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was using .html. The below fixed the issue -

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ImageTable td.ImageCell').each(function () {
        var cellItem = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://localhost:5001/Shipment/GetImage?' + $(this).html(),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                cellItem.append(data);
            }
    });
});
    </script>
}
```